# Writing toJSONValue methods with nested EJSON types?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two custom types, `Board` and `Tile`. Both need to be `EJSON` compatible. However, `Board` contains a two dimensional array of `Tile`s:

```
function Board(size) {
  this.tiles = [];
  for (var row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    this.tiles[row] = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < size; col++) {
      this.tiles[row][col] = new Tile(row, col);
    }
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

My question is regarding the `toJSONValue` method on `Board`. Do I need to explicitly convert the nested `Tile`s like this:

```
Board.prototype.toJSONValue = function() {
  var value = {};
  value.tiles = _.map(this.tiles, function(row) {
    return _.map(row, function(tile) {
      return tile.toJSONValue();
    });
  });
  return value;
};
```

Or will the nested `EJSON` type automatically be converted, allowing me to just do something like this:

```
Board.prototype.toJSONValue = function() {
  return { tiles: this.tiles };
};
```

I suspect that the first way would cause my `Tile` objects to be treated as plain objects rather than using the `EJSON` interface I've defined for them. But the second way seems like it would be an invalid use of the `toJSONValue` method. This makes me wonder if it's even possible to nest custom types with `EJSON`?

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify will work not just on arrays but also on arrays of arrays. For example, using the JavaScript console to demonstrate:

[image: JavaScript console screenshot]

So in your case, your last function, with just the one-line return, should work. Does it not?

See also [this article](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-create-a-custom-ejson-type); basically to create a custom EJSON type, you need to define a way to represent your data as a standard JSON-serializable type (plain object, array, etc.). Your array of arrays is already a compatible JSON-serializable type, so it should work as-is.